# Ignore margin-top when wrapped to the next line

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs, each with a top margin. But when the screen width gets too small, one or more of them slide to the next line, which is correct behavior. The problem is that I don't want the top-margin for those.

Can I somehow ignore / reduce the top-margin for divs that get wrapped to the next line?

Comment: Post your working code here

Comment: use css media query for that

Comment: Why do I get down votes for my question? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a wrapper div around those 4 divs. The wrapper I gave the margin-top and I deleted them from each div inside them. So the items in the first line still have their margin to the top and the ones which get wrapped down won't have the margin!

Comment: No this is the solution to my problem actually, I somehow can not mark it as answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your declaration in a `@media` rule with `min-width`, as such (example for 1024px) :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    div.MY_DIV{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

This will display the margin-top only if the screen is larger than 1024px, you just have to find the minimal screen width where all 4 elements are side by side.